# How to get value of next iteration in current iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, algorithm

I am under a situation where i am not able to get the logic to prepare this algorithm about how to do .

I have sequence of images have arrow between each image alternatively.Like this: `Image - > Image - > Image - > Image`

Where these arrows are also images of arrow having sum value over them.
    Now i have to display value of image in previous arrow (ofcourse the first image has no previous arrow so we have to deal with next image value (image at 3rd position) to display its value on previous arrow (arrow image at second position))

From here we will have image path and values (I am sorry if json is not correct but please focus on what i am trying to know)

```
  [{imagename1: "image1.png@", image1Value1:"imValue1@"},{imagename2: "arrowimage2.png@", image1Value2:"arrValue2@"},{imagename3: "image3.png@", image1Value3:"imValue3@"},{imagename4: "arrowimage4.png@", image1Value4:"arrValue4@"},{imagename5: "image5.png@", image1Value5:"imValue5@"}, {imagename6: "arrowimage6.png", image1Value6:"arrValue6@"},{imagename7: "image7.png@", image1Value7:"imValue7@"}, {imagename8: "arrowimage8.png@", image1Value8:"arrValue8@"}]
```

and here is what i want to achieve : http://prntscr.com/am3337

See here json in which i have to implement logic :

```
    $(json).each(function(i, val) //here i receive all images
     {
       var counter=1;

                $.each(val, function(key, val)  //this value is the value contained about arrow image
                {
                        var splitted = val.split('@'); 
                        var iamgename=splitted[0];//first parameter
                        var imageValue=splitted[1];//second paremeter

                        //how to get the next iteration value on current iteration (lets say if i am on second iteration , how can i get the third iteration image value here) 
                }
      }
```

My question is how can i save the value of current iteration to display on previous arrow image. (The display part i can do my self) . But the problem is, lets say for example i am under third iteration of loop  `$.each(val, function(key, val){}`. Now at third iteration i have `splitted[0]="image3.png"` and `splitted[1]="imValue3"`, to display imValue3 above arrowimage2.png is bit difficult (how to go one iteration back saving the current iteration value?). Or other solution could be that being at second iteration, try to get the value of third iteration(i could have done it like this value[i+1] if it was for loop where i=2, i can still get value of i=3 by one increment, but i do not know how to do it in `$.each(val, function(key, val){}` loop) **Is there any idea some one could suggest me to overcoem this problem ?**

Comment: is your `JSON` similar to a `HTML` like `<img 1> <img Arrow> <img 2> <img Arrow> <img 3> <img Arrow> <img 4>`?

Comment: json is like this :[{imagename1: "image1.png", image1Value1:"imValue1"},{imagename2: "arrowimage2.png", image1Value2:"arrValue2"},{imagename3: "image3.png", image1Value3:"imValue3"},{imagename4: "arrowimage4.png", image1Value4:"arrValue4"},{imagename5: "image5.png", image1Value5:"imValue5"}, {imagename6: "arrowimage6.png", image1Value6:"arrValue6"},{imagename7: "image7.png", image1Value7:"imValue7"}, {imagename8: "arrowimage8.png", image1Value8:"arrValue8"}] (i am sorry if i misinterpret you)

Comment: and i display images by generating html like this stringbuilder.push('<div style="width:100px; height:140px;" class="inline ' + imageFlowStatus + "\"" + '><asp:Panel style="display:inline-block;"><table width="100%  height="140px"><tr><img class="roundedcorners" align="middle" style="width:100px;height:112px;" src="' + splitted[0] + '" name="productimage2"></tr><tr><td  style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:#1caf9a;"> "' + splitted[2] + '"</span></td></tr></table></asp:Panel></div>');
                                  $('#imageDivs').append(stringbuilder.join(''));

Comment: But please go to how to get the next iteration value in current iteration. I knwo to display if i got the value of next iteration in current iteration.

Comment: Don't use jQuery, use JavaScript and iterate over array using for loop.

Comment: a quick question @struggling, do you mean, when you iterate `imagename1` you need to get value of `image1Value1` ?

Comment: I am using jquery because i have ajax call which calls a webservice and that webservice returns that json :[{imagename1: "image1.png", image1Value1:"imValue1"....} which i have to iterate upon for processing and displaying those images by creating html-divs though code which deomstrated in 3rd comment in same thread.

Comment: @ameenulla0007 quick reply to you: No, When i am at imagename2 then i wish to get imValue3, (imagename2 is at iteration 2 and at iteration 2, i wish to get the value of next iteration which is "imValue3"). I do so because at each iteration i display either an image or an arrow containg value of it's next image, please see this which i have to generate and let me knw if u r still confused ?  http://prntscr.com/am3337

Comment: @ameenulla0007 here on this link the first block is image1.png and seconnd is arrow(arrowimage2.png) having value of next iteration on it which is "imageValue3"

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = [{imagename1: "image1.png", image1Value1:"imValue1"},{imagename2: "arrowimage2.png", image1Value2:"arrValue2"},{imagename3: "image3.png", image1Value3:"imValue3"},{imagename4: "arrowimage4.png", image1Value4:"arrValue4"},{imagename5: "image5.png", image1Value5:"imValue5"}, {imagename6: "arrowimage6.png", image1Value6:"arrValue6"},{imagename7: "image7.png", image1Value7:"imValue7"}, {imagename8: "arrowimage8.png", image1Value8:"arrValue8"}];

var counter = 1;
$(json).each(function(i, val) {
    var nextImageName   = json[counter]["imagename"+(counter+1)]; //your next image content is here.
    $.each(val, function(key, newVal) {
        var splitted        = newVal.split('@'); 
        var iamgename       = splitted[0];
        var imagecontent    = splitted[1];
    });
    counter++;
});
```

here it is, the line `var nextImageName = json[counter]["imagename"+(counter+1)];` will return you with your next iterating image path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will test it tomorrow mornign will mark u as answer if it works :)

Comment: but please note that this "imagename" is not same in all sub sets of json in this line "json[counter]["imagename"+(counter+1)]". Its like imagename1 ,imagename2,imagename3..and so on.

Comment: yup, i believe, this would work, if you feel something salt to be added, we'll do it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could save the value is to assign it to the outer scope of the function so you could always overwrite it once you used it`var outerScope = 'some initializing'
function blub{
process outerScope //maybe you want to check its initializing value on first Iteration
outerScope = myNewValue 
}`

Comment: sorry i really do not understan what u mean ? could you please relate it to my example of image name at splitted[0] and value at splitted[1]  and how to get the value of next splitted[1]  being at current iteration ? or please give me any example and explain so that i understand well?